# How can I make the audit system create new audit files if they already exist?

Tags: oracle, security, oracle-10g

I am trying to make my audit files easier to read, I have audit trail configured as xml,extended. The problem is that if my server gets busy and reuses the pids - the logs are being appended to the same file.

I understand that there is a way to create a new file with suffixes if the audit file already exists. How can I do that? I use Oracle 10.0.4.0

Comment: Is that 10.2.0.4?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any reference to being able to directly manipulate the audit file names in 10g.  The closest thing I found is Bug 6023472 which lists the following changes introduced in 10.2.0.5/11.1.07/11.2.0.1:

- OS/XML Audit filenames will have a filename format of the form:
    `<InstanceName>_<ProcessName>_<ProcessID>_<SerialNo>.<Extension>`
- The default value for Max Audit FileSize is 1000KB and Max Audit File Age is 1 Day. This means that once one of these max limits are 
  reached, the audit records will be written in a new audit file with same 
  "`<InstanceName>_<ProcessName>_<ProcessID>_`" part, but with a new "`<SerialNo>`".

I'm not sure how Oracle assigns PIDs, but you could try increasing your PROCESSES parameter to see if that keeps it from re-using the values as quickly.

Comment: I hope this capability does exist and I just wasn't able to find it.